# Command prompt taking too long to appear after ssh connection

Tags: ssh, bash

I have a server that is acting really weird and hopefully you will help me find out what is happening. Here are the facts:

- The server has 2 users: `root` and `myuser`
- The server accepts only ssh connections using pubkey
- If I connect to the server as `myuser` from Putty (on Windows) the connection take a few seconds and the cmd prompt appears right away
- If I connect to the server as `myuser` from Cygwin (on Windows) the connection take a few seconds but it takes like 40 seconds for the cmd prompt to appear. The same occurs when connecting from a PHP script or even with `ssh` from another linux server in the same network
- On Cygwing I'm using `OpenSSH_7.2p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g`, on PHP the `phpseclib` library and on the other linux server `OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips`
- Trying the same procedure with `root` produces the same results

So, the ssh connection is stablished correctly in both cases (the sshd logs write `session opened for user myuser`) but in one case the cmd prompts appears right away and in the other it takes way too long (60 seconds).

Any ideas what might couse the problem? If you need some more info about logs messages or config files let me know in the comments.

**UPDATE 1**

Running `strace ssh myuser@1.2.3.4` outputs the following:

```
**lot of stuff**

18:20:10 read(3, "Dq\340\342\5\16\7+\367\366r\315\241\272\35\23\2225\344\366\332D\36\217\254$
18:20:10 ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=60, ws_col=237, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
18:20:10 getsockopt(3, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [0], [4]) = 0
18:20:10 setsockopt(3, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
18:20:10 getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(40713), sin_addr=inet_addr("190.9$
18:20:10 setsockopt(3, SOL_IP, IP_TOS, [16], 4) = 0
18:20:10 select(7, [3], [3], NULL, NULL) = 1 (out [3])
18:20:10 write(3, "?32\275\177\356\212x\177\334>\352K\226\225)\225\3507\361Zu,I\7!\273Hv1\31$
18:20:10 select(7, [3], [], NULL, NULL) = 1 (in [3])
18:20:10 read(3, "\37\347\207\273\236\244\22\314\222\305\23\270\206zl\270X\225i0\30\207\343f$
18:20:10 select(7, [3 4], [], NULL, NULL) = 1 (in [3])
18:20:10 read(3, "J2\345\334\336\350\364\225<D\t\305Y\23\366\341!_\351\310\357C\252I\322|\3\$
18:20:10 select(7, [3 4], [5], NULL, NULL) = 1 (out [5])
18:20:10 write(5, "Last login: Fri Mar  4 18:19:33 "..., 58) = 58
18:20:10 select(7, [3 4], [], NULL, NULL) = 1 (in [3])

# Here is where it waits 60 seconds

18:21:10 read(3, ":\233\225\377P\216.\2u&\275\372\257\203\261\236\322aN\263\313\203\315\373\$
18:21:10 select(7, [3 4], [5], NULL, NULL) = 1 (out [5])
18:21:10 write(5, "\33[?1034h[securitybox@wordpress10"..., 41) = 41
18:21:10 select(7, [3 4], [], NULL, NULL) = 1 (in [4])
18:21:14 read(4, "e", 16384)            = 1
18:21:14 select(7, [3 4], [3], NULL, NULL) = 1 (out [3])
18:21:14 write(3, ":\24\266\315J\202w+\213i\320\314\251\vc\17\230\372\344\237\341\341o\256\3$
18:21:14 select(7, [3 4], [], NULL, NULL) = 1 (in [3])
18:21:14 read(3, "eS\362U<\346\345f\245\27\21\323<\30J\20\261%1hx&\7k\323 \240\n^-\1P"..., 8$
18:21:14 select(7, [3 4], [5], NULL, NULL) = 1 (out [5])
18:21:14 write(5, "e", 1)               = 1
18:21:14 select(7, [3 4], [], NULL, NULL) = 1 (in [4])
18:21:14 read(4, "x", 16384)            = 1

**more stuff**
```

**UPDATE 2**

Know I realized that after the *Last login:*, when it hangs up waiting, you can press <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> and it will show the command prompt right away. So, it looks like there is a process that is taking too long at the startup.

**UPDATE 3**

I increased the debug level on the server side and here is the lates outputs before hanging and waiting:

```
Mar  4 17:15:31 thisserver.hostname sshd[2279]: debug3: PAM: opening session
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2279]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user securitybox by (uid=0)
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2279]: User child is on pid 2301
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2279]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: PAM: establishing credentials
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 10037/10037
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: server_init_dispatch_20
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 0 win 1048576 max 16384
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: input_session_request
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug2: session_new: allocate (allocated 0 max 10)
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug3: session_unused: session id 0 unused
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: session_new: session 0
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: session_open: channel 0
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype no-more-sessions@openssh.com want_reply 0
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug3: Wrote 40 bytes for a total of 2701
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request pty-req reply 1
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req pty-req
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: Allocating pty.
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 26
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug3: mm_pty_allocate: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PTY
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 27
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2279]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 26
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2279]: debug3: mm_answer_pty entering
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2279]: debug2: session_new: allocate (allocated 0 max 10)
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2279]: debug3: session_unused: session id 0 unused
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2279]: debug1: session_new: session 0
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2279]: debug3: ssh_selinux_setup_pty: setting TTY context on /dev/pts/6
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2279]: debug3: ssh_selinux_setup_pty: done
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2279]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 27
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2279]: debug3: mm_answer_pty: tty /dev/pts/6 ptyfd 4
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2279]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc /dev/pts/6
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request shell reply 1
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req shell
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug2: channel 0: rfd 9 isatty
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug2: fd 9 setting O_NONBLOCK
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug3: fd 7 is O_NONBLOCK
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug3: Wrote 88 bytes for a total of 2789
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2302]: debug1: Setting controlling tty using TIOCSCTTY.
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug3: Wrote 88 bytes for a total of 2877
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2302]: debug3: Copy environment: SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2302]: debug3: Copy environment: SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2302]: debug3: Copy environment: SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=
Mar  4 17:15:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2302]: debug3: channel 0: close_fds r -1 w -1 e -1
```

Then after a while, at the same time the prompt appears, it prints:

```
Mar  4 17:16:32 thisserver.hostname sshd[2301]: debug3: Wrote 72 bytes for a total of 2949
```

There you can see that it took 60 seconds. It **always** takes exactly 60 seconds.

Here is the output of the same log when connecting using Putty (remember that using Putty makes the prompt appear right away).

```
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug3: PAM: opening session
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug2: cipher_init: set keylen (16 -> 32)
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug1: Entering interactive session for SSH2.
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug1: server_init_dispatch_20
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug1: server_input_channel_open: ctype session rchan 256 win 16384 max 16384
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug1: input_session_request
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug1: channel 0: new [server-session]
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug2: session_new: allocate (allocated 0 max 10)
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug3: session_unused: session id 0 unused
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug1: session_new: session 0
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug1: session_open: channel 0
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug1: session_open: session 0: link with channel 0
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug1: server_input_channel_open: confirm session
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug3: Wrote 52 bytes for a total of 3185
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request pty-req reply 1
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req pty-req
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug1: Allocating pty.
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug1: session_pty_req: session 0 alloc /dev/pts/7
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug3: ssh_selinux_setup_pty: setting TTY context on /dev/pts/7
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug3: ssh_selinux_setup_pty: done
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug3: Wrote 36 bytes for a total of 3221
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request shell reply 1
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req shell
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug2: channel 0: rfd 8 isatty
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug3: Wrote 88 bytes for a total of 3309
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5508]: debug1: Setting controlling tty using TIOCSCTTY.
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug3: Wrote 100 bytes for a total of 3409
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5508]: debug1: PAM: reinitializing credentials
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5508]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5508]: debug3: Copy environment: SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5508]: debug3: Copy environment: SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5508]: debug3: Copy environment: SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5508]: debug3: channel 0: close_fds r -1 w -1 e -1
Mar  4 17:44:45 thisserver.hostname sshd[5505]: debug3: Wrote 84 bytes for a total of 3493
```

**UPDATE 4**

I found out that the process is hanging on the system call:

```
select(7, [3 4], [], NULL, NULL
```

This was the output of `strace -p $PID` where `$PID` is the pid of the ssh program while permforming the connection.

Comment: 1) Give it a try with `-vvv` switches to ssh and see in which point it waits. 2) If it will not be helpful, run the same command under `strace -r`. It should also give you some idea what takes so long. 3) I personally would blame DNS.

Comment: But the waits occurs after ssh has finished, or at least that is what it seems taking a look at the logs and to the `-vvv` output. Also `UseDNS no` is already set.

Comment: What means "*after ssh has finished*"? If the client logs will not be helpful, then you will probably have to try the same on the server. But it looks weird that it works from PuTTY and not from `ssh`. What is the version of openssh you have under cygwin?

Comment: I mean it has finished stablishing the connection. It seems that the connection is completed but starting up bash takes too long (I really am not expert at all)

Comment: So post the result of `strace`, as I proposed. There is much more things going on under the hood than only "*stablishing the connection*".

Comment: @Jakuje I've updated the question. Take notice that I've updated also that this isn't working on a PHP script in addition to Cygwin. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The logs differ in user: `securitybox` x `root` (but both uid=0). But the first one is using privilege separation (more logs) and the second does not (this is not much known bug where SELinux might interfere. We were fixing that in Fedora recently). Does it behave the same if you try from PuTTY with `securitybox` and from commandline with `root`? Or with some other non-privileged user from both?

Comment: What are your users ids and primary groups?

Comment: @Jakuje: the user `securitybox` is the one I'm trying to use. The problem happens too when I use `root`, I mixed the logs by mistake. I couldn't understand what do you need.

Comment: Please update the logs to match the same user, but different source (putty/ssh, fast/slow). And add please a bit more of context. after the hang.

Comment: @Jakuje, thaks for your time but I just gave up. I'll have to wait this 60 seconds everytime my scripts logs in.

Comment: It's you choice.

Answer (score 1):

sshd's reverse DNS lookup is always a candidate when you experience long login delays. You could try if setting

```
UseDNS no
```

in /etc/ssh/sshd.conf (and restarting sshd afterwards) fixes the issue.

Comment: But the waits occurs after ssh has finished, or at least that is what it seems taking a look at the logs and to the `-vvv` output. Also `UseDNS no` is already set.

Comment: what about nsswitch? Do you have some additional backends, for example ldap?

Comment: Nothing extra as far is I know.

Comment: Not in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning up the debug levels on the server side, rather than the client.

It sounds like maybe something in the PAM stack is taking a while (possibly that's what is doing slow lookups etc, rather than sshd itself). Verbose logging on the ssh server side should tell you which pam module (if any) is slowing things down and there are usually options to enable verbose logging of those modules that might help.

Comment: I have updated teh question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Cool - now if you try with the 'fast' user, you may be able to figure out how each ssh login is flowing through the sshd and get some clue where to look next.

Comment: Do you mean using the method which doesn't hangs waiting the prompt? I tried that and noticed a `PAM: reinitializing credentials` when connecting with Putty, but no idea what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging off of BeerSerc's answer, using the following approach on UBUNTU LTS 14.05.5, I accomplished a faster appearance of the command prompt after supplying SSH username and password credentials with the following alterations to my Linux system:

```
...become root using su or preface the next two (2) lines with the sudo command...

#cd /etc/ssh
#vi sshd_config

...navigate to end of file, add following text...

# GL    2017-02-25      Turn off DNS lookups to speed up the appearance
#                       of the command prompt after SSH username and
#                       password have been supplied
UseDNS no

...save file and exit editor...

#/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```